# No suitable driver found for jdbc in Spark

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using

```
df.write.mode("append").jdbc("jdbc:mysql://ip:port/database", "table_name", properties)
```

to insert into a table in MySQL.

Also, I have added `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` in my code.

When I submit my Spark application:

```
spark-submit --class MY_MAIN_CLASS
  --master yarn-client
  --jars /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  --driver-class-path /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  MY_APPLICATION.jar
```

This yarn-client mode works for me.

But when I use yarn-cluster mode:

```
spark-submit --class MY_MAIN_CLASS
  --master yarn-cluster
  --jars /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  --driver-class-path /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  MY_APPLICATION.jar
```

It doens't work. I also tried setting "--conf":

```
spark-submit --class MY_MAIN_CLASS
  --master yarn-cluster
  --jars /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  --driver-class-path /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
  MY_APPLICATION.jar
```

but still get the "No suitable driver found for jdbc" error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is 3 possible solutions,

1. You might want to assembly you application with your build manager (Maven,SBT) thus you'll not need to add the dependecies in your `spark-submit` cli.
2. You can use the following option in your `spark-submit` cli :

   ```
   --jars $(echo ./lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')
   ```

   **Explanation :** Supposing that you have all your jars in a `lib` directory in your project root, this will read all the libraries and add them to the application submit.
3. You can also try to configure these 2 variables : `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf` file and specify the value of these variables as the path of the jar file. Ensure that the same path exists on worker nodes.

Comment: I added mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar into my jar and now I do not include it in my spark-submit cli. By doing this yarn-client still works but yarn-cluster doesn't.

Comment: can you also try to configure these 2 variables "spark.driver.extraClassPath" and "spark.executor.extraClassPath" in "SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf" file and specify the value of these variables as the path of the jar file. Ensure that the same path exists on worker nodes.

Comment: Setting "spark.driver.extraClassPath" works for me, thanks.

Comment: Setting "spark.driver.extraClassPath" works for me..  but can someone explain why should we provide this, although I have the same same driver-jar included in my uber-jar

Answer (score 11):

I had to add the `driver` option when using the `sparkSession`'s `read` function.

`.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")`

```
var jdbcDF - sparkSession.read
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<DBName>")
  .option("dbtable", "<tableName>")
  .option("user", "<user>")
  .option("password", "<password>")
  .load()
```

Depending on how your dependencies are setup, you'll notice that when you include something like `compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.8'` in Gradle, for example, this will include the Driver class at `org/postgresql/Driver.class`, and that's the one you want to instruct spark to load.

Comment: this works for me, but just need to add `.option("format", "jdbc")`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggestions shown here which didn't work for me (with mysql).  While debugging through the DriverManager code, I realized that I needed to register my driver since this was not happening automatically with "spark-submit".  I therefore added

```
Driver driver = new Driver();
```

The constructor registers the driver with the DriverManager, which solved the SQLException problem for me.