# SparkR job deal with dependencies

Tags: r, maven, apache-spark, sparkr

How to deal with **dependencies** in case of a **(interactive) sparkR** job?

I know java jobs can be submitted as a fat-Jar containing all the dependencies. For any other job the `--packages` option can be specified on the `spark-submit` command. But I would like to connect from *R* (Rstudio) using sparkR to my little cluster. (this works pretty straigth forward)

But I need some external packages e.g. to connect to a database (Mongo, Cassandra) or read a csv file. In *local* mode I can easily specify these packages on launch. This naturally does not work in the already running cluster.
https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook provides a very convenient mode to load such external packages at runtime.

How can I similarly **load maven-coordinate packages** into the spark classpath either during **runtime** from my sparkR (interactive session) or during **image creation** of the dockerized cluster?

Comment: I think this answer might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/36474504/1314742

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. But if the package has regular maven-coordinates is there the possibility to pre-load it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to configure these 2 variables : `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf` file and specify the value of these variables as the path of the jar file. Ensure that the same path exists on worker nodes. 
From [No suitable driver found for jdbc in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764505/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc-in-spark/34765000#34765000)