# Is it possible to use R package in sparkR?

Tags: r, sparkr

I'm studying about sparkR, and I know there are so many useful R package in CRAN. But it seems like R package can't be used in sparkR. I'm not sure about that.

Is it true??? If it's not, could you explain how import R package into sparkR?

Comment: Just out of interest, did you find any change to the answer recently or is the answer still valid? I assume so reading latest SparkR doc. Thx

Comment: I think Konrad gave the good answer, but I couldn't have done that in practice. while reading the tutorial, my project objective changed. However, I consider it is possible to use R package on Spark from includePackage.

Comment: Thanks as it concurs with my understanding as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that you may be referring to the `includePackage` command:

> SparkR also allows easy use of existing R packages inside closures.
>   The `includePackage` command can be used to indicate packages that
>   should be loaded before every closure is executed on the cluster.

*Source:* **[R frontend for Spark](https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/)**

Comment: If SparkR can use existing R packages, Why SparkR offer about two hundreds of API in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html? It's just for ease of use???

Comment: In effect, the question boils down to what is **SparkR**, from the [official documentation:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) *SparkR is an R package that provides a light-weight frontend to use Apache Spark from R. In Spark 1.6.1, SparkR provides a distributed data frame implementation that supports operations like selection, filtering, aggregation etc. (similar to R data frames, dplyr) but on large datasets.* I would suggest that you have a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/wiki/SparkR-Quick-Start) that neatly demonstrates practical usage.